# Eclipse plugin for IDL

Tags: eclipse, plugins, mozilla, xpcom, idl

Is there an Eclipse plugin for syntax coloring (and potentially other features related to) IDL?

The specific IDL that I'm working with is Mozilla's [XPIDL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XPIDL), so ideally I would like a plugin specifically for that, but if that doesn't exist, a more generic IDL plugin might still be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [LibreOffice Eclipse plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/loeclipse) does a pretty good job of highlighting IDL files.